# In PhpStorm 2019.2.3 function “Reformat Code” format blade code in wrong way

Tags: phpstorm, laravel-blade

In my Laravel 7.6 / blade / bootstrap 4 / flex app  I have a page where 
blocks of data which are shown in 2 columns on big device and in 1 column on small device, what is 
implemented with classes block_2columns_md/block_splitting_left_half/block_splitting_right_half
and it works as I expected  :

```
@extends($frontend_template_name.'.layouts.frontend')

@section('content')

    @inject('viewFuncs', 'App\library\viewFuncs')
    <article class="fill-area-content flexbox-item-grow page_content_container">

        <div class="column_content_left_aligned m-0 ml-3">
            {{ Breadcrumbs::render('home') }}
        </div>

        <div class="block_2columns_md m-0 p-1 page_content">
            <div class="block_splitting_left_23 m-0 p-3">

                @if( count($activeQuizVotes) > 0 )
                    <div class="column_content_centered bordered">
                        <h3 class="text-center">
                            Quizzes
                        </h3>


                        <div class=" bordered">
                            <?php $odd = true; $index = 1;?>
                            @foreach($activeQuizVotes as $nextActiveQuizVote)

                                @if($odd)
                                    <div class="block_2columns_md m-0 p-1">
                                @endif

                                <div class="@if($odd) block_splitting_left_half m-0 p-3 @else block_splitting_right_half m-0 p-3 @endif vote-item-wrapper">
                                    <div class="card ">
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            <span class="w-80 mx-auto px-4 py-1 rounded-bottom category-link primary border-info text-white">
                                                @if(!empty($nextActiveQuizVote->vote_category_name) )
                                                    <a href="{{ route('votes-by-category', $nextActiveQuizVote->vote_category_slug ) }}">
                                                        <strong>{{$nextActiveQuizVote->vote_category_name }} </strong>
                                                    </a>
                                                @endif
                                            </span>

                                            <div class="img-preview-wrapper">
                                                <?php $voteImagePropsAttribute = $nextActiveQuizVote->getVoteImagePropsAttribute();?>
                                                @if(isset($voteImagePropsAttribute['image_url']) )
                                                    <a href="{{ route('vote_by_slug', $nextActiveQuizVote->slug ) }}">
                                                        <img class="card-img-top image_in_3_columns_list"
                                                           src="{{ $voteImagePropsAttribute['image_url'] }}{{  "?dt=".time()  }}"
                                                           alt="{{ $nextActiveQuizVote->name }}">
                                                    </a>
                                                @endif
                                            </div>

                                            <h5 class="card-title">
                                                <a href="{{ route('vote_by_slug', $nextActiveQuizVote->slug ) }}">
                                                    {{ $nextActiveQuizVote->name }}
                                                </a>
                                            </h5>

                                            <p class="card-text">{!!  Purifier::clean(concatStr($nextActiveQuizVote->description,100))  !!}</p>

                                            <a href="{{ route('vote_by_slug', $nextActiveQuizVote->slug ) }}">
                                                Go to Quiz
                                            </a>
                                        </div> <!-- <div class="card-body"> -->

                                    </div> <!-- <div class="card "> -->

                                </div> <!-- block_splitting_left_half / block_splitting_right_half -->


                                @if(!$odd)
                                    </div>  <!-- <div class="block_2columns_md m-0 p-1"> -->
                                @endif


                                <?php $odd = ! $odd; $index++; ?>
                            @endforeach

                        </div>

                        <div class="column_content_centered bordered">
                            {{ $activeQuizVotes->appends([])->links() }}
                        </div>

                        <div class="column_content_centered bordered">
                            {{ Widget::run('LatestNews', [
                                'items_per_block' => 4,
                                'filter_published'=> 1,
                                'filter_is_homepage'=>1
                            ]) }}
                        </div>

                        <div class="column_content_centered bordered">
                            {{ Widget::run('LatestExternalNews', [
                                'items_per_block' => 10,
                                'filter_published'=> 1,
                                'filter_is_homepage'=>1
                            ]) }}
                        </div>

                    </div>


                @endif {{--                    @if( count($activeQuizVotes) > 0 )--}}

            </div>  <!-- <div class="block_splitting_left_23 m-0 p-3">  -->


            <div class="block_splitting_right_13 m-0 p-3">
                @include($frontend_template_name.'.layouts.right_menu_block' , [ 'show_questions_block' => true, 'show_most_rated_quizzes_block' => true,
                            'show_most_taggable_votes_block' => true, 'show_vote_categories_block'=> true ] )
            </div>{{--<div class="block_splitting_right_13" >--}}


        </div> {{--<div class="block_2columns_md">--}}

    </article>


@endsection
```

In my layout I have key blocks formatting:

```
       @if($odd)
           <div class="block_2columns_md m-0 p-1">
       @endif
        ...
       @if(!$odd)
           </div>  <!-- <div class="block_2columns_md m-0 p-1"> -->
       @endif
```

But when in my PhpStorm 2019.2.3 I select all content of the editor and run function “Reformat Code” 
I have invalid text formatted :

```
@extends($frontend_template_name.'.layouts.frontend')

@section('content')

    @inject('viewFuncs', 'App\library\viewFuncs')
    <article class="fill-area-content flexbox-item-grow page_content_container">

        <div class="column_content_left_aligned m-0 ml-3">
            {{ Breadcrumbs::render('home') }}
        </div>

        <div class="block_2columns_md m-0 p-1 page_content">
            <div class="block_splitting_left_23 m-0 p-3">

                @if( count($activeQuizVotes) > 0 )
                    <div class="column_content_centered bordered">
                        <h3 class="text-center">
                            Quizzes
                        </h3>


                        <div class=" bordered">
                            <?php $odd = true; $index = 1;?>
                            @foreach($activeQuizVotes as $nextActiveQuizVote)

                                @if($odd)
                                    <div class="block_2columns_md m-0 p-1">
                                        @endif

                                        <div class="@if($odd) block_splitting_left_half m-0 p-3 @else block_splitting_right_half m-0 p-3 @endif vote-item-wrapper">
                                            <div class="card ">
                                                <div class="card-body">
                                            <span class="w-80 mx-auto px-4 py-1 rounded-bottom category-link primary border-info text-white">
                                                @if(!empty($nextActiveQuizVote->vote_category_name) )
                                                    <a href="{{ route('votes-by-category', $nextActiveQuizVote->vote_category_slug ) }}">
                                                        <strong>{{$nextActiveQuizVote->vote_category_name }} </strong>
                                                    </a>
                                                @endif
                                            </span>

                                                    <div class="img-preview-wrapper">
                                                        <?php $voteImagePropsAttribute = $nextActiveQuizVote->getVoteImagePropsAttribute();?>
                                                        @if(isset($voteImagePropsAttribute['image_url']) )
                                                            <a href="{{ route('vote_by_slug', $nextActiveQuizVote->slug ) }}">
                                                                <img class="card-img-top image_in_3_columns_list"
                                                                     src="{{ $voteImagePropsAttribute['image_url'] }}{{  "?dt=".time()  }}"
                                                                     alt="{{ $nextActiveQuizVote->name }}">
                                                            </a>
                                                        @endif
                                                    </div>

                                                    <h5 class="card-title">
                                                        <a href="{{ route('vote_by_slug', $nextActiveQuizVote->slug ) }}">
                                                            {{ $nextActiveQuizVote->name }}
                                                        </a>
                                                    </h5>

                                                    <p class="card-text">{!!  Purifier::clean(concatStr($nextActiveQuizVote->description,100))  !!}</p>

                                                    <a href="{{ route('vote_by_slug', $nextActiveQuizVote->slug ) }}">
                                                        Go to Quiz
                                                    </a>
                                                </div> <!-- <div class="card-body"> -->

                                            </div> <!-- <div class="card "> -->

                                        </div> <!-- block_splitting_left_half / block_splitting_right_half -->


                                        @if(!$odd)
                                    </div>  <!-- <div class="block_2columns_md m-0 p-1"> -->
                                @endif


                                <?php $odd = ! $odd; $index++; ?>
                            @endforeach

                        </div>

                        <div class="column_content_centered bordered">
                            {{ $activeQuizVotes->appends([])->links() }}
                        </div>

                        <div class="column_content_centered bordered">
                            {{ Widget::run('LatestNews', [
                                'items_per_block' => 4,
                                'filter_published'=> 1,
                                'filter_is_homepage'=>1
                            ]) }}
                        </div>

                        <div class="column_content_centered bordered">
                            {{ Widget::run('LatestExternalNews', [
                                'items_per_block' => 10,
                                'filter_published'=> 1,
                                'filter_is_homepage'=>1
                            ]) }}
                        </div>

                    </div>


                @endif {{--                    @if( count($activeQuizVotes) > 0 )--}}

            </div>  <!-- <div class="block_splitting_left_23 m-0 p-3">  -->


            <div class="block_splitting_right_13 m-0 p-3">
                @include($frontend_template_name.'.layouts.right_menu_block' , [ 'show_questions_block' => true, 'show_most_rated_quizzes_block' => true,
                            'show_most_taggable_votes_block' => true, 'show_vote_categories_block'=> true ] )
            </div>{{--<div class="block_splitting_right_13" >--}}


        </div> {{--<div class="block_2columns_md">--}}

    </article>


@endsection
```

With invalid key blocks :

```
                        @if($odd)
                            <div class="block_2columns_md m-0 p-1">
                                @endif


                                @if(!$odd)
                            </div>  <!-- <div class="block_2columns_md m-0 p-1"> -->
                        @endif
```

Why so wrong formatting and in which way can I fix it ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug that is not yet resolved, please vote: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-48192